# How to prove absolute value inequality for limits?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

For example, we know $|a| < b \implies -b < a < b$. I want to show the following:

$\limsup |a_n| < \infty \implies -\infty < \limsup a_n < \infty$. How can I proceed?

This intuitively makes sense, but I am unfamiliar with proofs involving the $\limsup$.

We know that by definition:

The limit of sequence of $\sup |a_n|$ for $n \ge N$, where $N \ge 1$ is $\limsup |a_n|$.

$\limsup |a_n| < \infty \implies \limsup |a_n| \in \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$.

This means that the sequence of $\sup |a_n|$ for $n \ge N$, where $N \ge 1$ converges.

Also, I can say that $\sup |a_n| \ge \sup a_n \ge -\sup |a_n|$. Would it be correct to from here conclude:

$\infty > \sup |a_n| \ge \sup a_n \ge -\sup |a_n| > -\infty$ and pass the limit, gaining the result by transitivity and limit laws?

So, $\implies -\infty < \limsup a_n < \infty$?

Comment: Start with the definition.  What *is* $\limsup |a_n|$?

Comment: Is my reasoning correct @XanderHenderson ?

Comment: You seem to be arguing it *backwards*, and you haven't actually defined $\limsup|a_n|$, which is the first thing I suggested you do.  What *is* $\limsup |a_n|$?  How is that object defined?

Comment: Updated @XanderHenderson to include definition. Could you tell me how it is backward? I clarified the conclusion at the end.

Comment: $|a|\lt b$ of course implies $-b\lt|a|\lt b$, but that is less than useful; presumably you mean that $|a|\lt b$ implies $-b\lt a \lt b$ (without the absolute value...)

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. @ArturoMagidin